# Is my SPF record not valid?

Tags: spf

I have a problem with one of the email services. It rejects emails from my server. I contacted them and they answered that they check SPF records and I am sending emails from not authorised server.

This is my SPF record:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

It contains "a" and so far I was sure that it's enough and I can send mail from server which IP address is listed as A record. Do I need to include server's IP address?

Comment: Let's see the bounce message.

Comment: are you trying to send emails from gmail?

Comment: no, Gmail is accepting my email without problems. It's a small provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google recommends just `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all` as per http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178723

Comment: But what about "A"record? I wanted to know if there is a need to add: "ip4:myserversip" or is enough to add just "a".

Comment: As long as it's the same ip as the a record for the domain, it's enough. Also, you specified ~all vs -all. It means to soft fail. They shouldn't be rejecting the email only for a fail with the spf records. A key thing to verify is that reverse dns is working correctly for your server's ips.

Comment: Yes, reverse DNS is working correctly. All main email providers like Gmail, Yahoo. Hotmail accept mails from my server. It's only 1 small provider says I have problems with everything.